# use onload on text area element

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use onload on a `textarea` element.
Trying to figure out what am i doing wrong

`<textarea id="textarea_info" onload="resizeFunction()"></textarea>`

now just to check if it works in javascript i'm using alert:
i've tried:

```
document.getElementById("textarea_info").onload = function(){
    alert("lop");
};
```

and also:

```
function resizeFunction(){
    alert("lop");
}
```

i've tried onload and onLoad but that alert never got through...
the js file is included correctly

Comment: do you want to have the text area have some content inside of it when the page loads - almost like a placeholder ?

Comment: I don't think that the textarea support such event, it is not listed in the supported events and methods in the official MDN

Comment: no.the text area initially will be empty. i thought that onload is element specific and not generic i.e. only about page.
Anyhow any thoughts why alert doesn't go through???

Comment: Using `jquery` you can try code
`$("#textarea_info").ready(function(){
    alert(123214);
});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such event onload for text area.
Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement), about the methods, properties and events.

I assumed you want to init it with something for the first time.
For this simply do what ever you want straight away.

```
document.getElementById("textarea_info").WHATEVER_I_WANT_TO_DO
```

Comment: Is WHATEVER_I_WANT_TO_DO a function?

Comment: a function which is bound to the element like onclick or any custom event which you created and attached

Answer (score 9):

Supported HTML tags:

```
  <body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>
```

see [HTML onload Event Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp)