# expand all textareas without needing to click each one

Tags: javascript, css

I have my .jsp page set so each `textarea` element, when clicked, expands in size to show its full contents. The code that enables this is shown below.

But how do I modify this so all the `textarea` elements are pre-expanded on visit to the page?

My existing requires requires you click the specific textarea itself. I want to modify this so all textarea elements are expanded accordingly on page load, rather than a click event on the textarea itself.

**js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  ...
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
  
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.onclick = function() {
      this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) ? (this.scrollHeight) + 'px' : "1.5em";
    }
  });  
  ...
</script>
```

**css**

```
textarea {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 2px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    overflow:hidden
}

textarea:focus {
    height: 8em;
    width: 98%;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

I cobbled my existing code together from tips from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321656/use-onload-on-text-area-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321656/use-onload-on-text-area-element). Maybe this could be done in `css` alone, which would be even better.

Comment: Hi, can you please provide your HTML as well?

Comment: Comment out the click event.

Comment: @John that gives me "Uncaught TypeError: this.style is undefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the same code (replacing `this` with `element`) without the `click` handler. Also, the CSS `textarea:focus` seems redundant, so it can be elimintated.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('textarea').forEach(function(element) {
  //element.classList.add("focused");
  element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight) ? (element.scrollHeight) + 'px' : "1.5em";

});
```

```css
textarea {
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 2px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
    overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum
  <textarea>Area 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem IpsumArea 1 Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum
  <textarea>Area 2 Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum </textarea>
</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum
  <textarea>Area 3  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum  Lorem Ipsum </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but for some reason doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JWoodchuck Can you define "doesn't work"? Do you get an error in your console? Can you edit your question to include the relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: The height for each textarea is all the same, showing only the first line of contents.

Comment: If I change it to, say, element.style.height  = "10em", each textarea is that height instead. So maybe it's not recognizing the scrollHeight?

Comment: This seems promising, but it sizes each textarea to a fixed, uniform size, rather than a size that shows the full contents of each (which varies for each textarea). Maybe there's a way to put the "this.scrollHeight" into the css.

Comment: @JWoodchuck Well, that's what's strange about your code. On the one hand, you had static CSS for when a textarea got the focus and then you have dynamic for when it's clicked (which gives it the focus).

Comment: @JWoodchuck See my newest updated answer.

Comment: Well, clearly this works in the snippet. So there must be something weird in my code because the textareas are still not adjusting to show the full text - even though they do in my original code with the onclick when I click them. I'll have to keep messing around with it. Thanks for your help!